# BJT small-signal base resistor voltage

Tags: bjt, thevenin, small-signal, base

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faKILQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am doing a small signal analysis of the following common-emitter BJT stage and I am trying to calculate the voltage across r_π (v_π). I am applying Thevenin's theorem.

Do I keep r_π in the Thevenin circuit? Is the Thevenin resistance Rthev = Ri//Rb1//Rb2//r_π OR Rthev = Ri//Rb1//Rb2 + r_π ?

Comment: You need to think about **what part** of the circuit you want to replace with a Thevenin equivalent. If you are trying to use a Thevenin equivalent to find the voltage across r_π then you probably do not want r_π as part of the Thevenin equivalent.

Comment: It entirely depends on what you are trying to achieve. Sometimes you'll keep it; sometimes you won't. Given that you haven't said what you are aiming to do then it's impossible to say. I think, on this occasion, if you are truly trying to calculate the voltage across r_π then you should include r_π in your analysis. Whether you use Thevenin or not,  the presence pf r_π does affect the voltage across it.

Answer (score 1):

If you break the circuit as shown, then \$\text r_{\pi}\$ is not included in the calculation of the Thévenin resistance.

[image]

So you can replace everything left of the green 'X' with a voltage source of V1*(K/Ri) in series with a resistor of value K, where K = Ri||Rb1||Rb2 and treat it like a simple voltage divider. But keep in mind that the voltage applied to the divider is not V1, but  V1*(K/Ri).

P.S. If you include \$\text r_{\pi}\$  you can get the answer in a single step, but then you are not invoking M. Thévenin.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I keep r_π in the Thevenin circuit? Is the Thevenin resistance Rthev = Ri//Rb1//Rb2//r_π OR Rthev = Ri//Rb1//Rb2 + r_π ?

Answer: You put them all in parallel: **\$R_{thev} = R_i//R_{b1}//R_{b2}//r_π\$**
While \$r_π=h_{IE}\$

Input impedance across Vbe is defined as hie,
Where;

hfe : It is called the current gain  aka \$\beta \$
hie : It is the internal resistance,  hie=hfe/gm  aka \$r_\pi\$
hre : It is called reverse voltage gain
hoe : It is the output resistance at emitter.

Let's compare a small signal diode incremental load  ΔVf/If=Rd to a base-emitter diode in a small transistor.

[image]

\$h_{ie} \approx (hfe+1)*\frac{26mV}{Ie}=\dfrac{26}{Ib [mA]}\$ @ 25 'C

hie for input impedance of a common emitter with Re=0

### 2N3904

For some odd reason  Plotting Hie , hfe for 2N3904 , has better matching for \$hie=30.5 hfe/Ic\$ otherwise 17% error.  (k=30.5 vs  k=26 temperature coefficient)  , let hfe = hfe+1 for hfe >100

[image]

For the long answer, read [Ian Getreau's book](https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/WyKtDIrFQPigHMVB.pdf) 1979 from Tektronix. But there is a simple approach for small non-saturated signals.

For an accurate answer compute hie from the datasheet and estimate tolerance.

Comment: May I give a short comment to the above answer? In your contribution you have defined r-pi as r_pi=1/gm. This definition seems to be not in accordance with r_pi as used in the the original question. For my opinion, the inverse transconductance 1/gm is called "intrinsic emitter resistance r_e" (although I do not like this nomenclature at all). As a consequence, the quantity you call Rbe (capital letter?) is identical to the commonly used dynamic small-signal base-emitter resistance r_pi=r_be=h11=hie.

Comment: @LvW, I appreciate your assistance to edit my answer and correct my formula and syntax to show the Rin for Vbe when Ic = 1mA to illustrate the loading effects for  small signal and simplify the problem rather than an academic one that includes Early Effects, forward and reverse current gain and ignores bulk resistance.  rb and re  or using https://i.stack.imgur.com/h72AX.png  (+1)

Comment: Tony Stewart, I must admit that I really do not fully understand your reply. Please, do not hesitate to state if I am wrong or not. In your contribution I read Rbe=(beta+1)*r_pi. However, in the original question as well as in Spehro Pefhany`s answer it is clear that r_pi is the differential resistance of the B-E junction [dVbe/dIb]. So what is the quantity you call Rbe in the first line of your contribution? I think it is also in the interest of the questioner that this discrepancy is cleared up.

Comment: Perhaps the most simple and direct way to avoid misunderstandings is to use words for defining the quantities.  To me, the commonly used symbol for the slope of the input voltage-current characteristic (identical to the small-signal differential B-E resistance) is r_pi=h11=hie=d(Vbe)/Ib. Simple question: Right or wrong?

Comment: Right, but describe in terms of Ic/Ib ratio with bulk resistance  in junction for different transistors and thermal effects of offset drift from Pd. Since gm is not plotted in datasheets it is less directly useful yet the dominant parameter.

Comment: Perhaps there is a misunderstanding between us: I did not speak about the transconductance and it dominance at all. And also not about the bulk resistance or thermal effects! It was my only intention to point to the fact that the originator of the question (Alema 416) did use another (the commonly used) definition for r_pi - if compared with your definition (as written at the beginning of your contribution. I think such a discreapancy should be solved resp. corrected in order to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: @LvW why is it that datasheets have no correlation with your suggested formulae for base emitter resistance load factor requested in this question. Can you correlate?

Comment: At first, thank you for correcting your contribution. (Secondly, but not so important: I cannot see where I have mentioned a "suggested formulae for base emitter load factor". I only have tried to solve a discreapency between two different definitions).

Comment: Do you agree with my answer now?  What do you think causes the temperature factor error that minimizes the error to match the datasheet using hie'= 30.5 (hfe+1)/Ic. I used a spreadsheet to compute using 25'C plots > @LvW

Comment: Yes - I think you have combined the two relations: hie=hfe/gm and gm=Ic/Vt. Therefore, I agree with everything.  Thank you.